# Stack overflow accessing GAE entity with bidirectional unowned one-to-one relationship using JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I am writing a Java application for Google App Engine. I have two entities which I need to model as a bidirectional unowned one-to-one relationship:

The first object 'ContainableObject'

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class ContainableObject {

/*=== Data Model ===*/
@PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;

@Persistent
@Unowned
private Container container;
```

and the second 'Container'

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Container {

/*=== Data Model ===*/
@PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;

@Persistent
@Unowned
private ContainableObject containable;
```

A Container can be empty or contain one ContainableObject. A ContainableObject can be in a Container, can move between Container objects, or have no Container. I need to be able to get from Container --> ContainableObject and ContainableObject --> Container

I'm using v2 of the datanucleus plugin. Running integration tests via maven this model works great, but when I try to access it via my REST API I'm getting a stack overflow:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.<init>(FutureTask.java:45)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.newTaskFor(AbstractExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:91)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$PrivilegedApiAction.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:277)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$PrivilegedApiAction.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:262)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.doAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:216)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:179)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxy.java:184)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.makeAsyncCall(DatastoreApiHelper.java:59)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchGetBySize(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:351)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:296)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:78)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:75)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:31)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:75)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:62)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.get(WrappedDatastoreService.java:60)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.lookupOneToOneChild(FetchFieldManager.java:426)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchRelationField(FetchFieldManager.java:341)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:248)
at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2228)
at com.whatever.ContainableObject.jdoReplaceField(ContainableObject.java)
at com.whatever.ContainableObject.jdoReplaceFields(ContainableObject.java)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceNonLoadedFields(JDOStateManager.java:1988)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$1.fetchNonLoadedFields(EntityUtils.java:976)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2857)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1013)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.lookupOneToOneChild(FetchFieldManager.java:427)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchRelationField(FetchFieldManager.java:341)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:248)
at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2228)
at com.whatever.Container.jdoReplaceField(Container.java)
at com.whatever.Container.jdoReplaceFields(Container.java)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceNonLoadedFields(JDOStateManager.java:1988)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$1.fetchNonLoadedFields(EntityUtils.java:976)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2857)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1013)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.lookupOneToOneChild(FetchFieldManager.java:427)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchRelationField(FetchFieldManager.java:341)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:248)
at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2228)
at com.whatever.ContainableObject.jdoReplaceField(ContainableObject.java)
at com.whatever.ContainableObject.jdoReplaceFields(ContainableObject.java)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceNonLoadedFields(JDOStateManager.java:1988)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$1.fetchNonLoadedFields(EntityUtils.java:976)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2857)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1013)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.lookupOneToOneChild(FetchFieldManager.java:427)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchRelationField(FetchFieldManager.java:341)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:248)
at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2228)
at com.whatever.Container.jdoReplaceField(Container.java)
at com.whatever.Container.jdoReplaceFields(Container.java)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceNonLoadedFields(JDOStateManager.java:1988)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$1.fetchNonLoadedFields(EntityUtils.java:976)
```

Is this the wrong way to model this, or have I found an AppEngine bug?

Comment: no reason why "JDO" would have any problem with cyclic relations, since its what is present for RDBMS type models. Suggest you use latest SVN codebase and see if that is different since your stack trace doesn't line up with anything recent. You could easily look at the tests for GAE JDO unowned 1-1 bi relations at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/jdo/JDOUnownedOneToOneTest.java

Comment: the tests look pretty much like they should work. I did switch to use 3.1.2-SNAPSHOT from maven2-nightly but I'm getting a ton of errors now, such as `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.store.ExecutionContext.findObject(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/datanucleus/store/FieldValues;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
 at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1013)`

Comment: Why change DN version ? the GAE JDO plugin is what you should change (and pick the DN jars to match it)

Comment: After switching to the SVN version (2.1.2-SNAPSHOT) with DN core 3.1.1, enhancer 3.1.0-release I get the same error with a slightly different stacktrace http://pastebin.com/TGE8PDse

Answer (score 1):

You say its a **bidirectional** relation, yet you don't have a **"mappedBy"** on one side of the relation. So it is currently 2 **1-1 uni** relations.

If it is intended to be 2 1-1 uni relations then you need to report the problem to Google on the GAE JDO/JPA plugin project with a testcase to reproduce it.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference between a bidirectional 1-1 relationship and two 1-1 unidirectional relationships. My understanding was that the mappedBy annotation was for owned relationhips, since this will set the 'parent' in the child key. My objects are unowned, in different entity groups. I tried adding mappedBy arbitrarily to one side, but I have the same error. When I get some time, I will try this with a smaller object model to see if I can reproduce it in a way that I can report to Google. Thanks

Comment: 2 1-1 unis can have different objects at the other side, whereas a bidir will have consistent objects at the two sides. And no "mappedBy" is not for "owned" relations (since there is no such thing in JDO or JPA).

Comment: Thanks. This is not the answer to this question but its really useful information, not explained anywhere in Google's docs. Will make sure it is really a bidir in my testcase.

Comment: Note to anyone with problems re: 1-N with GAE DataStore JDO: `class User { @Persistent(mappedBy = "user") List<Favorite> favorites }` and `class Favorite { @Persistent(mappedBy = "favorites") User user }`. Note that when I annotated `Favorite.user` to be `@Unowned`, meaning the `Favorite` doesn't own the `User`, it still failed; in this case it makes the whole relationship `@Unowned`, but I wanted User to own `Favorite`s. I suggest to put a breakpoint in com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchRelationField to see what relation type DataNucleus recognised.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your class ContainableObject has a reference to an object of type  Container and in the class Container has a reference to an object of type ContainableObject, so it may create a circular reference that may drive crazy JDO.

Try to get rid of on the references and see if this works.

Comment: Thanks. I did try as you suggested, and arbitrarily made one side of the relationship store a Key (as you had to in JDO 2.3) and that got rid of the stack overflow. However I'm going to try the suggestion in the other comment from @DataNucleus first before marking this as the answer, as they point out that it should work!